# PostgreSQL Include special characters in copy/import

Tags: postgresql, import, include, copy

This is a very quick question on using the postgresql copy feature to import a csv file.

If I have a row with data such as

```
random, 1689, rnd\\168
```

how do I include the special characters \ so that it appears in the db as

```
random
1689
rnd\\168
```

Comment: is this a sample data ?? how many columns are therein your table that you're trying to import ??

Comment: there are hundreds of rows but that row is the only one with the two backslashes, the problem is that there could be more with two backslashes in the future so I'd like to know how to deal with them

Answer (score 0):

What about simply using the [copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command?

```
copy my_table from 'full_csv_file_path' with  CSV delimiter ',';
```

[image]

And the CSV file is containing:

```
random,1689,rnd\\168
```

Comment: that is the command I am using the problem is that it treats '\' as a special character (new line I think). So I know I can edit the csv file by including double quotes to escape the '\' as such ""\""""\"" but then they don't show up at all, I need a way to include them and not escape them

Comment: The csv file contain this string: `random, 1689, rnd\168` or `random, 1689, rnd\\168`?

Comment: It countains this string `random, 1689, rnd\\168` (it has two backslashes)

Comment: So, if you do the command like in my answer, you will have `rnd\\168` as it is and the  `\\` are not escaped